# How to make use of class_weights to calculated custom loss fuction while using custom training loop (i.e. not using .fit )

Tags: tensorflow, gradienttape

I have written my custom training loop using `tf.GradientTape()`. My data has 2 classes. The classes are not balanced; `class1` data contributes almost 80% and `class2` contributes remaining 20%. Therefore in order to remove this imbalance I was trying to write custom loss function which will take into account this imbalance and apply the corresponding class weights and calculate the loss. i.e. I want to use the `class_weights = [0.2, 0.8]`. I am not able to find similar examples.

However all the examples I am seeing are using model.fit approach where its easier to pass the `class_weights`. I am not able to find out the example which uses `class_weights` with custom training loop using `tf.GradientTape`.

I did go through the suggestions of using `sample_weight`, however I don't have the data where in I can specify the weights for samples, therefore my preference is to use class weight.

I am using `BinaryCrossentropy` loss as loss function but I want to change the loss based on the `class_weights`. That's where I am stuck, how to tell `BinaryCrossentropy` to consider the `class_weights`.

Is my approach of using custom loss function correct or there is better way to make use of `class_weights` while training with custom training loop (not using `model.fit`)?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Facing similar problem ...

Answer (score 1):

you can write your own loss function. in that loss function call BinaryCrossentropy and then multiply the result in the weight you want and return that

Comment: amin thanks for your suggestion. I am struggling to do the same thing due to following observations.
When I get the loss from BinaryCrossentropy loss function, its returned as a single value, therefore I am not able to calculate the weighted average. I was trying to get the loss for each class so that I could apply the weight for each class but looks like loss function doesn't work that way.

Comment: I looked at discussion thread at https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2115 but there are too many discussion points, so I am kind of lost. I tried to use one of the weighted loss functions but getting errors related to reshaping. May be that thread is discussing about categorical cross entropy but I am trying to use it for BinaryCrossentropy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation that should work for `n` classes instead of just 2.

For your example of `80:20` split, calculate weights as below (assuming 100 samples in total).

1. Weight calculation (ref: [Handling Class Imbalance: TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#class_weights)):

   ```py
   weight_class_0 = (1/count_for_class_0) * (total_samples / num_classes) # (80%) 0.625
   weight_class_1 = (1/count_for_class_1) * (total_samples / num_classes) # (20%) 2.5
   class_wts = tf.constant([weight_class_0, weight_class_1])
   ```
2. Loss function: Requires labels to be sparse and logits unscaled (no activations applied).

   ```py
   # Example logits=[[-3.2, 2.0], [1.2, 0.5], ...], (sparse)labels=[0, 1, ...]
   def weighted_sparse_categorical_crossentropy(labels, logits, weights):
       loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels, logits)
       class_weights = tf.gather(weights, labels)
       return tf.reduce_mean(class_weights * loss)
   ```

You can supply this loss function to custom training loops.